# getting datetime from current timestamp default

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

When users first create their accounts it by default puts the current timestamp in the "date" field which is a timestamp type.

It won't allow me to make the default value the current datetime if the field type is "datetime". I can only do that with "timestamp".

But now I'm needing to use date_diff() which requires a datetime format. Is there a way to convert the timestamp result into datetime so I can put it into date_diff?

I could manually go back in to every page where it creates new accounts and make it find the current date and then put it into a datetime field, but that would be a ton more work obviously (which I'll do if necessary).

There's not really any code to show. Here's where I get the value from the database (function sends the query "SELECT date FROM user_login WHERE username = $username"):

```
$udate = get_value("user_login", "date", "username", $_SESSION['user']['username']);
```

The value returned is the date and time but not in a datetime format. So when I try the following:

```
date_diff($udate, date(Ymd), true);
```

It gives the error

> date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

Comment: Or to put it another way, how do you convert "2015-06-17 12:38:54" into a datetime value which can be used with date_diff()?

Comment: Maybe [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It won't allow me to make the default value the current datetime if the field type is "datetime". I can only do that with "timestamp".

MySQL will allow you to specify a field of `DATETIME` with a default value of `NOW()`. This will get translated by MySQL to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Then, when a user is created, MySQL will insert the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into your `date` field automatically.

[MySQL Date and Time Functions NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

---

**EDIT:**

It looks like your issue is with `date_diff` itself. You must provide the first two arguments as type `DateTime`, but your timestamp representation from your MySQL database is a `string`. Create a DateTime object and pass that as your argument:

```
$udate = new DateTime(get_value("user_login", "date", "username", $_SESSION['user']['username']));
$now = new DateTime();

$diff = date_diff($udate, $now, true);

// Will spit out difference in days
echo $diff->format('%d days');
```